# django allauth not creating user account after Oauth login

Tags: django, django-allauth

I've installed django-allauth via pip.
I've set it up for Github logins, and that works as Github shows that my app has one user.
However, after I do the authorization at Github, I get redirected to this page:
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/social/signup/`
which renders my base.html template (copied from django-allauth), but doesn't indicate that I'm logged in.
When I check the django admin site and my database, I don't see any new users in my Users, or new entries in Social Accounts or Social Tokens.
My callback is set to:
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/github/login/callback/`

Answer (score 2):

I had to dig in the allauth code and found out the answer.
The reason for receiving this page was that I had a registered user with the same mail trying to signup using FB which caused a conflict.

Solution : Create a template at socialaccount/signup.html and add a form.as_p there.

Worked form me

Comment: I already signed up a user in my db to my Github account. I then changed the oauth app keys and then tried to resign in. I thought it would create a new user for the new Github app but it it seems it tried to reconnect with the old app. I then reset the db and it worked.

Comment: They need to add user merging and a user merging strategy / event.

Answer (score -1):

If you end up at `/accounts/social/signup/` you are not signed up, yet. At this stage, you have successfully authenticated with the social account provider, but you need to submit a few more details (e.g. your e-mail address in case the provider did not hand it over) to complete your account. Only after completing this stage you will be successfully signed up & logged in.

Comment: Hi I am still looking for the answer to this question and don't understand where to go from here. Please provide a lead such as : Which template to create ? How to get rid of this (assuming that I don't care for more information)? Thanks!

Comment: @pennersr user not created after Google one tap login. Call back function is called but failed to create user. See Rok Strniša's answer at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64234915/how-to-integrate-google-one-tap-login-with-django-allauth/73707538?noredirect=1#comment130689863_73707538