# How to integrate Google One Tap login with django-allauth?

Tags: django-allauth, google-identity

How does one integrate the Google One Tap login experience with django-allauth?

1. django-allauth is integrated and working great for simple username/password logins.
2. I have Google OneTap's nicer user experience recognizing the user's authenticated Google account and offering to continue via that, sending a JWT auth token to Django.
3. Trying to find the simplest / cleanest way to register the new user account with the OneTap token and treat them as authenticated.

Appreciate any suggestions.

**Refs:**

- https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web
- https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Update Feb 8, 2024]
**Added a step by step tutorial on** [how to implement Google One Tap Login with Django](https://aisaastemplate.com/blog/django-allauth-google-login-prompt/)

Hacked something together, not as slick as one click login, (takes one extra step)

See more details here
https://twitter.com/DataLeonWei/status/1368021373151375361

All I did was changing the google redirect URL to the existing user log-in page with Google.

And add an additional view and replace google's data-login_uri with this view's URL.

```
@csrf_exempt
def google_one_tap_login(request):
    login_url = PUBLIC_DOMAIN_NAME + '/accounts/google/login/'
    return HttpResponseRedirect(login_url)
```

If someone has a better solution, please let me know.

My current hack is implemented on both [sqlpad](https://sqlpad.io) and [skills.ai](https://skills.ai), please feel free to check them out and see it in action.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I asked this 5 months ago and found a different solution (non OneTap), but am still interested in accepting/approving this solution if I can confirm it works. Looks promising based on the Twitter screenshots shared. I'll try to give it a shot soon to see if I can reproduce the functionality you demonstrated.

Comment: You are welcome, thanks. My current hack is implemented on [sqlpad's website](https://sqlpad.io) , please feel free to check it out and see it in action.

Comment: Confirming that looks great! Marking answer as accepted.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Override allauth's `account/login.html` template and render the Google button (remember to replace `<GOOGLE_APP_CLIENT_ID>` and `<HOMEPAGE>`):

```html
<div class="g_id_signin" data-type="standard" data-shape="pill"
     data-theme="outline" data-text="signin_with" data-size="large"
     data-logo_alignment="left"></div>

<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="<GOOGLE_APP_CLIENT_ID>"
     data-context="signin"
     data-ux_mode="redirect"
     data-login_uri="<HOMEPAGE>{% url 'google-login' %}?next={{ request.GET.next }}"
     data-auto_prompt="false"></div>

<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

Install `google-auth` if you haven't already:

```bash
pip install google-auth
```

Register the `google-login` endpoint in your `urls.py`:

```py
path('google-login', views.google_login, name='google-login'),
```

Define the `google-login` endpoint in your `views.py`, where you [verify the Google ID token](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token) before redirecting to `allauth`'s login URL for Google:

```py
import logging
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponseBadRequest
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from google.oauth2 import id_token
from google.auth.transport import requests
from urllib import parse

@csrf_exempt
@require_POST
def google_login(request):
    body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
    body_params = parse.parse_qs(body_unicode)
    csrf_token_cookie = request.COOKIES.get('g_csrf_token')
    if not csrf_token_cookie:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest('No CSRF token in Cookie.')
    csrf_token_body = body_params.get('g_csrf_token')
    if not csrf_token_body:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest('No CSRF token in post body.')
    if csrf_token_cookie != csrf_token_body[0]:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest('Failed to verify double submit cookie.')
    next_url = request.GET['next']
    try:
        token = body_params.get('credential')[0]
        # noinspection PyUnusedLocal
        idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, requests.Request(), settings.GOOGLE_APP_CLIENT_ID)
    except ValueError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return HttpResponseBadRequest('Failed to verify Google auth credentials.')
    return redirect(settings.HOMEPAGE + '/accounts/google/login/?next=' + next_url)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Asked this a couple years ago and settled on a different solution (non-OneTap). Don't have time to confirm this works at present, but appreciate knowing the solution exists.

Comment: @Rok Strniša This code does not show up 'Google One Tap login'. I use ngrok for local https. Let me know is there anything else to be done to make your code working?

Comment: @Hariprasad Did you replace GOOGLE_APP_CLIENT_ID and HOMEPAGE with appropriate values? Do you see anything in the browser console or server logs?

Comment: @Rok Strniša I have replaced GOOGLE_APP_CLIENT_ID and HOMEPAGE. I can able to login but no user created and there is no user session.

Comment: @Hariprasad I believe the user should be created the first time it comes to `/accounts/google/login/`, which is where they are redirected at the end of `google_login `. Maybe try debugging by overridding `ACCOUNT_ADAPTER` and `SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER`.